# Issue with posting the sibling value to API (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm developing a school management system.

I have a division list which i'm getting from a web service, next to every division list there is add button if i want to add a grade inside the selected division, the issue is when i click on any add button it always add inside the first division.

for ex: if i clicked on the add button next to the third division, it will post inside the first division.

I want the new grade to be posted inside the selected division to add.

I tried to give the division button the value of the division.id, the id is showing when i click inspect, but it's not being posted to the web service, always gives me undefined or posts only the first division ID.

My component HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-12 " *ngFor="let division of divisionList, let i = index">
    <form #create='ngForm'>
        <button *ngIf="division" class="choose-list arrow-onclick1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#list1" id="getId" name="division_id"
                [(ngModel)]="division.id" value="{{division.id}}">
            {{division.name}}
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right pull-right arrow-down-onclick1" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-top: 12px"></i>
        </button>
        <!--Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter grade name...</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" name="name" ngModel #name="ngModel" placeholder="Name...">
                        <!--<input type="text" name="division_id" placeholder="{{division.id}}" 
                        value="{{division.id}}" #division_id="ngModel" ngModel  >-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                                (click)="createGrade(create)">Create grade
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

My component TS:

```
division_id: number[] = [];

createGrade(form: NgForm){
    this.division_id = $(this).closest('#getId').val();
    let data = form.value;
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('grades[0][name]', data.name);
    formData.append('grades[0][division_id]', this.division_id);
    this.http.post(this.url, formData)
        .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Screenshot that may help:

Division view (the grades are the dummy text inside)

[image: Division view (the grades are the dummy text inside)]

[Link](https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/grades/CreateGrades) to the divisions API (POST).
[Link](https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/admin/grades/division) to the divisions API (GET).

Kindly if anything is not clear enough tell me as this project is very important to me, so i need to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Create Grade button, use this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="createGrade(create, division.id)">Create grade
</button>
```

i.e. pass `division.id` from template local variable, as you are doing it here:

```
<button ... [(ngModel)]="division.id" value="{{division.id}}">
```

Then in `createGrade` handler, receive it as second argument and use:

```
createGrade(form: NgForm, divisionId: number){
    let data = form.value;
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('grades[0][name]', data.name);
    formData.append('grades[0][division_id]', divisionId);

    ...
}
```

Comment: it's adding, but if i added a grade inside the second division, still appears inside the first division which means i always post the first division, i want to know how to make the click event catches the id that belongs to the selected division.

Comment: Inside `createGrade`, can you `console.log(form, divisionId);` and see in dev tools, what it prints when you click. Also in dev tools *network tab*, see which **id** is sent with the request.

Comment: Still prints the first id even if i clicked on the second or third

Comment: Then problem is in the template. All buttons are opening the dialog for the first division. Let me examine.

Comment: On the arrow button you have attribute `data-target="#list1"`. Means it open/expands a modal with id **list1**. Where is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165777/discussion-between-abdul-wahab-and-mohamed-wahshey).